# Simple scrapy spider doesn't crawl

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to get number of pages crawled by the spider using the `'pages_crawled'` attribute. However, no matter the kind of website I try, I am getting `pages_crawled`= None.
Below is my code:

```
from threading import Thread 
from selenium import webdriver
from urlparse import urlparse
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from scrapy.statscol import StatsCollector

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "mySpider"
    def get_url():
        url = raw_input('Enter the url of your website (including the http)')
        return url 
    start_url = str(get_url())
    extractor = SgmlLinkExtractor()
    rules = (Rule(extractor, callback='web_crawling',follow=True),)
    def web_crawling(self):
       settingObj=Settings()    
       crawler=Crawler(settingObj)
       stat = StatsCollector(crawler)
       depth = stat.get_value('pages_crawled')
       return depth
```

Why do I keep getting the none-value?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change line

```
start_url = str(get_url())
```

so that start_url is a list:

```
start_urls = [str(get_url())]
```

Then change line

```
def web_crawling(self):
```

by adding an additional parameter to your parse function:

```
def web_crawling(self, response):
```

---

Here's a working version of your code:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.settings import Settings
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler
from scrapy.statscol import StatsCollector

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "mySpider"
    def get_url():
        url = raw_input('Enter the url of your website (including the http)')
        return url 
    start_urls = [str(get_url())]
    extractor = SgmlLinkExtractor()
    rules = (Rule(extractor, callback='web_crawling',follow=True),)
    def web_crawling(self, response):
       settingObj=Settings()    
       crawler=Crawler(settingObj)
       stat = StatsCollector(crawler)
       depth = stat.get_value('pages_crawled')
       return depth
```

To test the above code, save it in file `spidey.py`. Then install Scrapy with VirtualEnv and run it with the Scrapy executable like so:

```
virtualenv venv
venv/bin/pip install scrapy
venv/bin/scrapy runspider spidey.py
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply; just one more question. when I am trying to invoke web_crawling by doing `scrapy = MySpider()
    pages_crawled = MySpider.web_crawling(scrapy,...)`, what should I put for the second argument of the call `MySpider.web_crawling()`? do I just put `response`? or to put it even simpler, how can I invoke `web_crawling` function?

Comment: I'm not sure how to invoke the spider programatically--my only experience is using the Scrapy runtime executable. But I added to my answer simple instructions on how to do this using Python virtualenv. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

better add it as a scrapy [extension](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/topics/extensions.html)

see also [stats extension](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/stats.html)

in practice, add extensions.py to the root directory of scrapy project:

```
from scrapy import signals

class ExtensionThatAccessStats(object):

    def __init__(self, stats):
        self.stats = stats

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        # instantiate the extension object
        ext = cls(crawler.stats)
        crawler.signals.connect(ext.spider_closed, signal=signals.spider_closed)
        return ext

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        spider.log("spider stats %s" % self.stats.get_stats())
```

from spider log:

```
>>> [dmoz] DEBUG: spider stats {'log_count/DEBUG': 52, 
'scheduler/dequeued': 2, 'log_count/INFO': 3, 
'downloader/response_count': 2, 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2, 
'response_received_count': 2, 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2, 
'downloader/response_bytes': 14892, 'finish_reason': 'finished', 
'start_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 3, 17, 50, 41, 253140),      
'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2, 'scheduler/enqueued': 2, 
'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2013, 12, 3, 17, 50, 41, 544793), 
'downloader/request_bytes': 530, 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2, 
'downloader/request_count': 2, 'item_scraped_count': 44}
```

to make the extension active, don't forget to add the following to the project's settings.py:

```
EXTENSIONS = {
    'project_name.extensions.ExtensionThatAccessStats': 100,
}
```